# Integration by parts question: why does the constant of integration get swallowed up?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, fake-proofs

To integrate $e^x\cos x$ we can use integration by parts twice:
\begin{align}
\int e^x \cos x \, dx &= e^x\sin x - \int e^x\sin x \, dx \\
&= e^x\sin x - \left(-e^x\cos x + \int e^x\cos x \, dx\right) \\
&= e^x\sin x + e^x\cos x - \int e^x \cos x \, dx \\
2 \int e^x\cos x \, dx &= e^x(\sin x + \cos x) \\
\int e^x \cos x \, dx &= \frac{e^x(\sin x + \cos x)}{2}
\end{align}
But this solution is incomplete: there should be a constant of integration at the end. Why does this happen? I think it might have something to do that you are adding a family of functions to itself, but I can’t quite pin down what the problem is.

Comment: Bringing the integral from the right to the left side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you have something more like $F(x)=e^x \sin(x) - G(x)$ then $F(x)=e^x \sin(x) + e^x \cos(x) - H(x)$, where $F$ and $H$ are both some antiderivatives of $e^x \cos(x)$ (not necessarily the same ones) and $G$ is some antiderivative of $e^x \sin(x)$. Now $F$ and $H$ differ only by a constant, so $2F(x)=e^x \sin(x) + e^x \cos(x) + C$ and then you divide.

In practice if you want to take derivations seriously, you're better off with definite integrals with variable limits, i.e. working with $\int_a^x f(y) dy$ instead of $\int f(x) dx$.

Comment: Hi Ian. Thanks for this answer. It does make more sense to look at things from this angle. However, if we want to define the notation $\int f(x) \, dx$ precisely, then can it refer to a set of antiderivatives? In other words, can we define $\int f(x) \, dx$ as $\{F(x) \mid F' = f\}$? And if so, where would the error in this proof be?

Comment: @Joe Sure, but this way of doing things has mildly annoying algebraic properties. For example $\int f(x) dx + \left ( -\int f(x) dx \right )$ is $\{ x \mapsto c : c \in \mathbb{R} \}$ rather than $x \mapsto 0$ as you would initially expect. Missing this fact is what led to your question in the first place.

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with set notation, but I presume that $\{ x \mapsto c \mid c \in \mathbb{R} \}$ refers to the family of constant functions. You've convinced me that defining the indefinite integral this way is not easy and/or desirable, but if we do take this approach, then how would we define the addition of two indefinite integrals? In other words, is there a sensible way of defining $\{F(x) \mid F' = f\} + \{G(x) \mid G' = g\}$, for instance?

Comment: @Joe Yes, $\{ x \mapsto c : c \in \mathbb{R} \}$ is the set of all real-valued constant functions. And sure, there is an addition operation: it's $\{ x \mapsto F_0(x) + G_0(x) + c : c \in \mathbb{R} \}$ where $F_0$ and $G_0$ are any particular elements of the two sets you're trying to add. When you get used to it, this isn't that bad, but if you aren't used to it, you get confused when, for example, subtracting an indefinite integral from itself doesn't "really" result in $0$.

Comment: @Joe Note that this is the same as $A+B=\{ x \mapsto F(x) + G(x) : F \in A,G \in B \}$, which is maybe the more obvious way to write it, but one should keep in mind that given $f \in A+B$ there is not a unique decomposition of $f$ as $g+h$ where $g \in A$ and $h \in B$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. Another thing thing about writing $\int f(x) \, dx = F(x) + C$ that people find objectionable is how we use the equals sign—it should actually be an equivalence sign, apparently. Is it possible if you elaborate about what the difference between the equals sign and the equivalence sign is? Don't worry if you don't have the time or energy—you've already been very helpful to me.

Comment: @Joe Basically you can say either $\int f(x) dx \sim F(x)$ where $\sim$ is the relation on *functions* for "differ by only a constant". In this usage $\int f(x) dx$ is a function. Or you can say $\int f(x) dx = \{ F(x) + C : C \in \mathbb{R} \}$. In this usage $\int f(x) dx$ is a set. The conventional indefinite integral notation is shorthand for either one of those. These two don't *technically* mean the same thing, because they differ in what type of thing $\int f(x) dx$ is defined to be in the first place. But the distinction is not really important when you understand what's going on.

Comment: I think you have mostly cleared up my confusions, but I'm not entirely sure how I would interpret $\int f(x) \, dx$ as a function. For instance, if we wrote $\int 2x \, dx \sim x^2$, then does the LHS refer to *any* derivative of $2x$, or a particular antiderivative?

Comment: @Joe In that case the LHS is a single not-explicitly-specified antiderivative. Not a very useful way of doing things, I agree.

Comment: In general, is there something about antiderivatives that make them less fundamental or less useful than, say, definite integrals or derivatives? I always got the impression that they are a distraction from what calculus is *really* about. There are other problems, too: they are a little tricky to define, as evidenced by our discussion; and they don't generalise easily to higher dimensions. Perhaps they are only of interest because they can be used to comptute areas. This is probably quite an open-ended question, but do you have any thoughts about this?

Comment: @Joe To me antiderivatives are rarely the right object, they're more like a lazy hack when you want to forget about the constant for the moment. Usually there is some sensible way to define an $a$ so that you can replace $\int f(x) dx$ with $\int_a^x f(y) dy$. In fact doing this can sometimes help with confusion; for example, when you are solving a separable ODE $y'=f(t) g(y)$, instead of doing $\frac{dy}{g(y)} = dt f(t)$ and then somehow applying $\int$ (with no differential) to both sides, you can just do $\int_{t_0}^t \frac{y'(s)}{g(y(s))} ds = \int_{t_0}^t f(s) ds$.

Comment: @Joe (Cont.) What is happening with separable ODEs is much clearer that way, IMO. Anyway, just in general, where antiderivatives are actually the thing you want is in finding the general solution to an ODE. But even in the setting of ODE, the fundamental significance of FTC is not "explicit antiderivatives let you analytically evaluate integrals of nice functions". It is really "integrals let you numerically evaluate antiderivatives of weird functions".

Comment: I suppose it is also that it is much more important that we know that antiderivatives of all continuous functions *exist*, than to have a nice way of expressing the definite integral of a 'tiny' subset of continuous functions. And, as you have said, the FTC makes numerical integration easy.

Answer (score 2):

In order to find $\int f(x)\,dx$ (on an interval $I$), all one needs is to find **one** differentiable function $F:I\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $F'(x)=f(x)$ for every $x\in I$. Then
$$
\int f(x)\, dx=F(x)+C
$$

This is the *definition* of indefinite integrals. This definition is based on the observations that

- If $F:I\to\mathbb{R}$ is such that $F'=f$ on I, then for *any* constant $K$, $(F+K)'=f$ on $I$;
- If $G:I\to\mathbb{R}$ and $F:I\to\mathbb{R}$ are such that $G'=F'$ on $I$, then there exists a constant $K$ with $G=F+K$. (This is why it is important that $I$ is "connected", i.e., an interval on $\mathbb{R}$.)

---

Now go back to your integral where $f(x)= \int e^x\cos x$, $I=\mathbb{R}$. The formal<sup>$\dagger$</sup> calculation just gives you **one** $F$ such that $F'=f$ on $I$, which give you the answer:
$$
\int e^x\cos x\,dx=\frac{1}{2}e^x(\sin x+\cos x)+C. 
$$

---

<sup>$\dagger$</sup> The reason it is "formal" is that by definition,
$$
\int f(x)\,dx
$$
means a family (set) of functions (on $I$); but in the calculation, one uses only one "instance" of the set. This is OK since one can eventually add the "arbitrary constant" $C$ to get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have an indefinite integral,
there is a constant of integration.

When you make the limits definite,
the constant is subtracted away
since it occurs in
both the lower and upper limit.

Answer (score 0):

This solution to your problem makes use of a very basic fact. Note that $\int f(x)~dx=\int f(x)+0~dx$
$$\begin{align}\int e^x \cos x \, dx&= e^x\sin x - \left(-e^x\cos x + \int e^x\cos x \, dx\right)\\
&=e^x\sin x+e^x\cos x-\int e^x\cos x \, dx\\
&=e^x\sin x+e^x\cos x-\int e^x\cos x \, dx+\int0~dx\end{align}$$
Hence,
$$2\int e^x\cos x \, dx=e^x\sin x+e^x\cos x+C$$